# How can I programmatically open the DateChooserPanel when my frame gets shown

Tags: java, datechooser

I'm using the DateChooser Lib from Androsov Vadim which can be found here:
[Sourceforge Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdatechooser/files/)

What I want to achieve is, simply show the popup menu when the frame gets shown.
Here is a simple implementation of the DateChooserCombo

```
package testapp;

public class TestFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public TestFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    dateChooserCombo1 = new datechooser.beans.DateChooserCombo();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(124, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(dateChooserCombo1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(121, 121, 121))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
            .addComponent(dateChooserCombo1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(258, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private datechooser.beans.DateChooserCombo dateChooserCombo1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

This is how it looks now:

[image: DateChooserCombo]

And this is what i want to achieve:

[image: DateChooserCombo with shown menue]

If someone has done the same and could help me achieving this would be great.

Comment: have you tried dateChooserCombo1.doClick();

Comment: Yes but i get the error message "cannot find symbol symbol: method doClick()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple attempts to solve this issue I downloaded the source of the Lib and edited the visibility of the method dateChooserLoaded from private to public, build the jar and implemented this edited version of the Lib into my Project.

After that i can now simply call it like this:

```
@Override
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
    dateChooserLoaded();
}
```

maybe this helps someone else with a similar problem.